# Can I make the "Hey Siri" popup go away without using my mouse/keyboard?

Tags: mac, siri, monterey

After saying "Hey Siri... do " I am always left with the Siri popup and have to press Escape or use the mouse to remove it:
[image]

It seems odd a voice assistant requires manual input to dismiss and this popup remains visible on top of screensaver, etc IIRC. Is there a voice command to dismiss Siri or a setting to make it auto-dismiss after replying to me?

Answer (score 0):

Simply telling Siri to "go away"  will dismiss the pop-up. As for auto-dismissal, I'm unaware of such a setting.